# How to build the longest String with different Unicode characters

Tags: java, string, unicode

Thanks in advance for your patience. This is my problem.
I'm writing a program in Java that works best with a big set of different characters.
I have to store all the characters in a String. I started with
private static final String values = "0123456789";
Then I added A-Z, a-z and all the commons symbols.
But they are still too few, so I tought that maybe Unicode could be the solution.

The problem is now: what is the best way to get all the unicode characters that can be displayed in Eclipse (my algorithm will probably fail if there are unrecognized characters - those displayed like little rectangles). Is it possible to build a string (or some strings) with all the characters present here (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) correctly displayed?

I can do a rough copy-paste from http://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/euroml/tests/test-ucspages1ucs.html or http://zenoplex.jp/tools/unicoderange_generator.html, but I would appreciate some cleaner solution.
I don't know if there is a way to extract characters fron a font (the Unifont one). Or maybe I should parse this (www. utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) webpage.

Moreover, by adding all the characters into a String I will probably get the error:
"The type generates a string that requires more than 65535 bytes to encode in Utf8 format in the constant pool" (discussed in this question on SO: /questions/10798769/how-to-process-a-string-with-823237-characters).

Hybrid solutions can be accepted. I can remove duplicates following this question on SO questions/4989091/removing-duplicates-from-a-string-in-java)

Finally: every solution to get the longest only-different-characters string is accepted.
Thanks!

Comment: "those displayed like little rectangles" - That is font-dependent or file-format dependent. Some symbols requires certain fonts and others require file formats.

Comment: I was trying a big base-conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing some things up. The question whether a character can be displayed in Eclipse depends on the font you have chosen; and whether the source file can be processed correctly depends on which character encoding you have set up for the source file. When choosing `UTF-8` and a good unicode font you can use and display almost any character, at least more than fit into a single `String` literal.

But is it really required to show the character in Eclipse? You can use the unicode escapes, e.g. `\u20ac` to refer to characters, regardless of whether they can be displayed or if the file encoding can handle them.

And if it is not a requirement to blow up your source code, it’s easy to create a `String` containing all existing characters:

```
// all chars (i.e. UTF-16 values)
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(Character.MAX_VALUE);
for(char c=0; c<Character.MAX_VALUE; c++) sb.append(c);
String s=sb.toString();
// if it should behave like a compile-time constant:
s=s.intern();
```

or

```
// all unicode characters (aka code points)
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(2162686);
for(int c=0; c<Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; c++) sb.appendCodePoint(c);
String s=sb.toString();
// if it should behave like a compile-time constant:
s=s.intern();
```

If you wan’t the `String` to contain valid unicode characters only you can use `if(Character.isDefined(c)) …` inside the loop. But that’s a moving target— newer JRE’s will most probably know more defined characters.

Comment: Thanks. All the characters are generated!

Answer (score 0):

Smply use Apache classes, org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils (commons-lang) can solve your purpose.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Also please refer to below code for api usage,

```
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class RandomString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Random string only with numbers

  String string = RandomStringUtils.random(64, false, true);

  System.out.println("Random 0 = " + string);


  // Random alphabetic string

  string = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(64);

  System.out.println("Random 1 = " + string);


  // Random ASCII string

  string = RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(32);

  System.out.println("Random 2 = " + string);


  // Create a random string with indexes from the given array of chars  

  string = RandomStringUtils.random(32, 0, 20, true, true, "bj81G5RDED3DC6142kasok".toCharArray());

  System.out.println("Random 3 = " + string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but since I need them all, why should I use a random-tecnique? Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Operations for random Strings.

Currently private high surrogate characters are ignored. These are unicode characters that fall between the values 56192 (db80) and 56319 (dbff) as we don't know how to handle them. High and low surrogates are correctly dealt with - that is if a high surrogate is randomly chosen, 55296 (d800) to 56191 (db7f) then it is followed by a low surrogate. If a low surrogate is chosen, 56320 (dc00) to 57343 (dfff) then it is placed after a randomly chosen high surrogate.

Comment: Please refer to api documentation for more details, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: Sorry, I saw the documentation and edited the message, but I haven't been fast enough.
I can use the radom(int) method, but I would have to call it many times to get all the possible characters. I will have to use progressive epuration... I can't have duplicates...